# Trying to center my fixed banner on my blog

Tags: css, center, tumblr, fixed, banner

After researching code after code for the past week on this site, I have yet to find a one that centers my fixed banner. I am now at my wits end and desperately seeking for help.

Here is the what i have so far:

```
.heading {
    position:fixed;
    z-index:1;
    overflow:hidden;
    color:{color:background};
    background-color:{color:background};
    top:0px;
    left:5%;
    right:95%;
    margin-left:-570;
    font-size:11px;
    width:1030px; 
    height:auto;
    text-align:center;
    border-bottom:2px solid {color:text};
}
```

And this is what it looks like so far:

http://m-orning-star.tumblr.com/

Any input would be wonderful. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
.heading {
  left: 0px;  /* Changed this to 0 */
  right:95%; /* REMOVE this line */ <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
  margin-left: 0; /* Changed this to 0 */
  font-size:11px;
  width: 100%; /* Changed this to 100% */
  height:auto;
}
```